# How to Prevent RadMenu from closing on Mouse Right Click

Tags: wpf, telerik, contextmenu, right-click, radmenu

I have created `RadMenu` in my WPF application, and have added a Context Menu for `RadMenuItems` Following is the code/XAML of `RadMenu`

```
<telerik:RadMenu Name="radMenu1" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuHeaders}" Height="76">
                <telerik:RadMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="telerik:RadMenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Command"
                            Value="{Binding Command}" />
                            </Style>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <StackPanel Height="Auto">
                            <Image MaxWidth="32" MaxHeight="32" Source="{Binding mImage}" />
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding mText}"></TextBlock>
                            <Image MaxWidth="10" MaxHeight="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding mDownImage}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
                    <telerik:RadContextMenu>
                            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Add to Wishlist">
                                <telerik:RadMenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Source="/WPFTestApp;component/Images/New.png" />
                                </telerik:RadMenuItem.Icon>
                            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                    </telerik:RadContextMenu>
                </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
            </telerik:RadMenu>
```

The ContextMenu works fine but when I right click on the any `RadMenuItem` the ContextMenu is opened but the RadMenu is closed. I want to keep RadMenu opened but don't know how to do it?

Comment: Did you try adding StaysOpen="True" to your context menu?

Comment: @Xcalibur37, Thanks for your suggestion, but what I want is to force `RadMenu` to stay opened not the context menu. `StaysOpen` is property of `RadContextMenu`